# Google maps api and gMapsLatLonPicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm using gMapsLatLonPicker [plugin](https://github.com/wimagguc/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps) on a modal (foundation 6 reveal) and the problem is that I realized I need load manually the plug in in order to work in the modals for example:

```
$('#modal').on("open.zf.reveal", function(ev,elem) {
  /*when the modal fires open*/
  $(document).gMapsLatLonPicker().init( $(this) ); /*Init the plugin*/
});
```

But I don't want to initialize the plugin each time someone open the modal, do you know if there is another alternative for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this

```
var first_time = true;

$('#modal').on("open.zf.reveal", function(ev,elem) {
  /*when the modal fires open*/
  if(first_time==true){
      $(document).gMapsLatLonPicker().init( $(this) ); /*Init the plugin*/
      first_time=false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thought that could exist better solutions,but  yes, that is easy one,